# Не получается нарисовать секцию на bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap4

Нужно разместить блоки в секции вот в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А требования таковы:

1. Ширина `A+Б=100%` окна
2. Ширина `Б` - по своему содержимому
3. Высота всей секции - по содержимому `Б`
4. Высота `В` - по своему содержимому
5. Выравнивание `А` - по середине ширины и высоты
6. Выравнивание `Б` - по середине ширины и высоты
7. Выравнивание `В` - по середине высоты, по правой стороне ширины

Пока не получается выполнить `п.4-7`.
Просьба помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение помогли найти [на форуме Drupal](https://drupal.ru/node/136781), за что им безмерное человеческое спасибо!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">А</div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">В</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br>22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222&nbsp;22222<br></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос закрыт.